# How to use backslash in regex patterns?

Tags: python, regex, backslash

Simple regex task: find an ID (and language) within a string.

```
import re

txt = '<OB02 ID="1099367" LANG="FR">'
pattern = r'\\ID="(.*?)\\"'

result = re.findall(pattern, txt)
```

This gives an empty list as result. Leading to the questions:

- How to correctly encapsulate \" in python?
- How to extract ID and LANG from txt?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2828611

Answer (score 0):

## Use an [xmlParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse xml and not regex.

As a workaround you can use the following regex:

```py
import re

txt = '<OB02 ID="1099367" LANG="FR">'
pattern = 'ID="([^"]*)'

result = re.findall(pattern, txt)
```

As said, this is a bad idea, caus if someone now starts using single quotes or add comments, this will break.

Comment: That's exactly my first choice, too. But didn't work for this string (IMHO no proper XML). But very welcome if you find a way xml.etree.ElementTree can handle this.